# Compiler does not accept extern variables after including other library

Tags: c, extern

I have a problem, I need to extern variuables from one file to another and I need to include a library. the problem is that when I include the library the compiler gives an error saying that the variables are undefined.

External file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "PHY.h"

void InterruptHandler();

extern int flag;
extern long toSend;
extern int recieved;
void InterruptHandler()
{
    //here i use the flag
}
```

The main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "PHY.h"
void main()
{
    int flag;       //  DETERMINATES CLOCK STATUS
    int recieved;
    long toSend;    //  THE DATA WE WANT TO SEND (for instance 0x12345678)
    toSend  =   0x12345678; // EXAMPLE
    // .... here the code continues..
}
```

Comment: Are you including the external file somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried making the variables global (move them outside of `main`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make variables local to a function (for example, `flag` in `main()`) directly visible anywhere outside of the function, let alone reach them via `extern`.

You need to move those local variables to outside of `main()`, making them normal global variables. They'll be reachable via `extern` in your "external" file.

Also, since the code suggests that you're handling interrupts in it, make those global variables that are accessed in the ISR `volatile`. If you don't, changes to them may be invisible in the ISR or outside of it.

Comment: Even worse, `volatile` is not guaranteed to help you for signal handlers. The only type that is guaranteed by the standard is `sig_atomic_t` as of C99. Through the new C11 standard you could also use atomic types that have the "lockfree" property.

Comment: @JensGustedt I know. Let's do it in small steps.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, ok, the small step would just be to use `sig_atomic_t`.

Comment: @JensGustedt If available. Otherwise, one would need to see if there's any compiler extension or function and if not, implement it.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, `sig_atomic_t` is part of the C standard.

Comment: @JensGustedt We haven't been told what compiler the OP's using. For many things a C89 one is largely appropriate and sufficient.